# mqueue: message too long

Tags: c, mqueue

When I run the following program i have always the error message "Message too long". Why?

this is the source:

```
#define NAME "/q"
#define SIZE 16

void main()
{
mqd_t mq;
char buffer[SIZE+1];
struct mq_attr attr; 

attr.mq_flags = 0;
attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
attr.mq_msgsize = SIZE;
attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

mq = mq_open(NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644, &attr);
printf ("opening mqueue: %s\n", strerror(errno));

mq_receive(mq, buffer, strlen(buffer), NULL);
printf ("receiving: %s\n", strerror(errno));

printf ("message: %s\n", buffer);

unlink(NAME);
}
```

This is the outupt:

```
opening mqueue: Success
receiving: Message too long
message:
```

/*****new edit*****/

okok i changed the code for better eliminate some ambiguity

```
#define NAME "/q"
#define SIZE 1024

int main()
{
  mqd_t mq;
  char buffer[SIZE+1] = {0};
  struct mq_attr attr = {0}; 

  attr.mq_flags = 0;
  attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
  attr.mq_msgsize = SIZE;
  attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

  if ((mqd_t) -1 == (mq = mq_open(NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644, &attr)))
    printf("opening mqueue: %s\n", strerror(errno));

  if (-1 == mq_receive(mq, buffer, SIZE+1, NULL))
    printf("receiving: %s\n", strerror(errno));

  printf("message: %s\n", buffer);

  if (-1 == unlink(NAME))
    perror("unlink() failed");

  return 0;
}
```

output

```
receiving: Message too long
message: 
unlink() failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You shouldn't examine `errno` unless you know an error has occured. Test `mq_receive` return value.

Comment: it's -1 so, there's an error :(

Comment: What message are you expecting to receive? Maybe it's very large? Try to provide more complete data.

Comment: OT: It's `int main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are logging `errno` without being sure it had been set.

`errno` **only** carries a significant value **if an error condition was expliclty indicated** otherwise, typically by a function returning a specfic value indicating it failed.

You might like to modify your code to something like this:

```
#define NAME "/q"
#define SIZE 16

int main()
{
  mqd_t mq = ;
  char buffer[SIZE+1] = {0};
  struct mq_attr attr = {0}; 

  attr.mq_flags = 0;
  attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
  attr.mq_msgsize = SIZE;
  attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

  if ((mqd_t) -1 == (mq = mq_open(NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644, &attr)))
    printf("opening mqueue: %s\n", strerror(errno));

  if (-1 == mq_receive(mq, buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL))
    printf("receiving: %s\n", strerror(errno));

  printf("message: %s\n", buffer);

  if (-1 == unlink(NAME))
    perror("unlink() failed"); /* easier varaint of printf ("...: %s\n", strerror(errno));, also prints to stderr, where errors should go. */

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` is uninitialised, so `strlen(buffer)` will return some indeterminate value.

Change:

```
mq_receive(mq, buffer, strlen(buffer), NULL);
```

to:

```
mq_receive(mq, buffer, SIZE, NULL);
```

Comment: OK  - there are probably more bugs - check the value of `mq` immediately after the call to `mq_open` - if it's -1 then it failed.

Comment: @AlessandroMariani: However `strlen(buffer)` there is definitly wrong, as if the buffer would be initialised to all `0`s, `strlen(buffer)` would return `0`, which surely isn't what you want.